# how to do email verification by sending the mail in jsp

Tags: java, registration

I am having the registration form.After submitting it goes to another JSP page where it gets the data of that form and stores it in my database.Now i want to send the email to the user id which he has given for the confirmation.I don't have any idea about it. please get me code for it.
This is my registration form action and submit code.

```
<form action="signupdata.jsp" method="POST">
<input type="submit" onclick="" value="submit">
```

This is on signupdata.jsp to save the data in my database.

```
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into userdetails(firstname,lastname,email,password,cpassword,category) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+emal+"','"+pwd+"','"+cpwd+"','"+ctgry+"')");
```

Now I want to send the email of confirmation to the user's email ID like most of websites provides.

Comment: thanx,i have edited the question. please review it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below code in **firtPage.jsp**

```
<form action="signupdata.jsp" method="POST">
Please enter email : <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" onclick="" value="submit">
</form>
```

Write below code in **signupdata.jsp**

```
      // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
      String to = request.getParameter("email");

      // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
      String from = "SENDER_EMAIL";

      // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
      String host = "YOUR_EMAIL_HOST";

      // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      // Get the default Session object.
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject("SUVJECT_LINE");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("YOUR MESSAGE GOES HERE");

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Just replace dummy credentials with your actual credentials. If you get any exception let me know.

Comment: it gives error in these lines.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));

the errors are,cannot find sybol for .getDefaultInstance,cannot find sybol for MimeMessage,cannot find sybol for InternetAddress,cannot find sybol for RecipientType.

and also throws excpetion of MessegingException that it is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement.

Comment: Add java mail jar file in your program.

Comment: try to find at oracle site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.5-oth-JPR

Comment: i have added javamail1_4_4.zip to my libraries. and wrote down this import still it is not working. :(
<%@page import="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage"%>

Comment: you need jar file not zip file.

Comment: oops,sorry.Ok i have done it.Now it gives errors here.
1 MimeMessage(session); 
2 getDefaultInstance
3 RecipientType
4 .send
5 catch(MessagingException mex)
    {
    mex.printStackTrace();
    }

Comment: yes defenately.. please give me your mail id

Comment: what? i didn't get it.

Comment: oh that wasn't known by me. you asked me to do mail that's why i asked. so what should i do now?

Answer (score 2):

The exact code for the problem depends upon your project and can be too large to post here. I would recommend that instead of looking for code snippets you should ask for general solutions/libraries that fit your problem domain and then google for code samples based on that.

In this case you can use `Java Mail API` to send mails. Just google for Java Mail code samples.

If you are using Spring framework `JavaMailSenderImpl` provides a convenient way to send mails.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="com.kshitiz.MailUtil"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean id="mailSenderMain" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"
            p:host="${host}" p:port="${port}"
            p:username="${username}" p:password="${password}">
            <property name="javaMailProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then in code -

```
public class MailUtil {
    private MailSender mailSender;

    public MailUtil(MailSender mailSender)
    {
        this.mailSender=mailSender;
    }
    public void sendResetPasswordMail(String email, String password) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("mymail@gmail.com");
        message.setTo(email);
        message.setSubject("Your new password!");
        message.setText("Here is your new account login password - " + password);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

For verification you could add a field `auth_token` to your user_accounts table. This auth_token is a `UUID` generated at the time of registration. Then create a servlet that takes a parameter and verifies it against the database. Send the link to this servlet in the mail. If verification is successful erase the `auth_token` field marking the user as authenticated.

Comment: i am not using spring framework